# How to get Google spreadsheet chart with Zend Gdata

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-sheets-api

I am using Zend Gdata service for accessing Google spreadsheet details with authentication

My spreadsheet have cell data as well as Google charts, I am getting cell data correctly but not getting Charts

Let me know how should I achieve this

I have written below code

```
    $service = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
    $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient('EMAILADDRESS', 'PASSWORD', $service);
    $spreadsheetService = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);

    $spreadsheetKey = 'SPREADSHEETKEY';
    $query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_DocumentQuery();
    $query->setSpreadsheetKey($spreadsheetKey);
    $feed = $spreadsheetService->getWorksheetFeed($query);

    $query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_CellQuery();
    $query->setSpreadsheetKey($spreadsheetKey);
    $worksheetId = basename($feed->entries[0]->id);
    $query->setWorksheetId($worksheetId);


    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $cellFeed = $spreadsheetService->getCellFeed($query);
        $formdata = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        foreach ($cellFeed as $cellEntry) {
            $row = $cellEntry->cell->getRow();
            $col = $cellEntry->cell->getColumn();
            $val = $cellEntry->cell->getText();
            $updatedCell = $spreadsheetService->updateCell($row, $col, $formdata['txtUpdate'], $spreadsheetKey, $worksheetId);
        }
    }

    $cellFeed = $spreadsheetService->getCellFeed($query);
    $totalCol = 0;
    foreach ($cellFeed as $cellEntry) {
        $row = $cellEntry->cell->getRow();
        $col = $cellEntry->cell->getColumn();
        $val = $cellEntry->cell->getText();
        $arrData[] = array('row' => $row, 'col' => $col, 'val' => $val);
        $arrDataNew[$row][] = array('col' => $col, 'val' => $val);
        if ($col > $totalCol) {
            $totalCol = $col;
        }
    }
```

I have searched on internet about accessing Google chart via PHP but not got any help. Let me know if we can achieve this via Zend or in plain PHP also OK

Comment: Who have done markdown let me know why? Did we can't achieve this?

Comment: Google-apps-script will do it https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets But Is there a "charts" api for gdata? The Spreadsheet-API has nothing in it that can access charts type information.

Answer (score 0):

zend gdata uses the google spreadsheets api, which as you found out only suports retrieving data at the row or cell level. you cannot get anything else (charts, images etc)

only google apps script lets you [get at the sheet charts (api)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCharts()). if you must integrate it with something else, make an apps script content service published to be accessed public and anonymous
note not all chart types are supported.